# UIImage setImage is very, very slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, file-io, uiimage

I'm trying to load an image from a local URL using the following:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL]];
[self.imageView setImage:image];
NSLog(@"imageView set");
```

So I see in the console "imageView set" almost immediately, but it takes a very long time for it to be reflected in the UI (sometimes a few minutes!).

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What is the value of `fileURL`? What thread is this running on?

Comment: what is dimension , file size & file format of your image ?

Comment: fileURL is a gif in the documents directory. The filesize of the image is less than 1-2mb. The function is triggered by a IBAction but I assume it;s run on the main thread?

Comment: i have developed `Lazy UIImageView` for async image Downloading, which will solve your problem, you can download it from [here](https://github.com/DipenPanchasara/LazyImageView)

Comment: use imageWithContentsOfFile instead of imageWithData

Comment: @Madhu - gave it a try and the performance is the same.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara This is a local image, not a remote image.

Comment: it can work on both whether its from server or local.

Answer (score 10):

This happened to me when I was setting the image in a background thread (in which I was downloading the image file). Just make sure your code is run in the main thread. The image will change immediately.

```
// In a background thread...

UIImage *image = ... // Build or download the image

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
    [self.imageView setImage:image]; // Run in main thread (UI thread)
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You should load up instruments and see what exactly it is doing.

For starters, you should do what you can to avoid I/O on the drawing thread. Also, are there other I/O requests at the same time?

A `UIImage` does not necessarily need to be a singular bitmap representation -- it may be backed by a cache and/or loaded lazily. So just because an 'image' is 'set', does not mean that the optimal bitmap has been loaded into memory and prepared for rendering -- it may be deferred until render (draw) is requested.

Profiling OTOH will tell you (generally) why it is taking longer than expected.

Comment: Thanks. I should definitely do that. The only other thing going on in the page is playing a video from a remote URL.

Comment: @AndyHin well, if that heavy video stuff is synchronous and performed on the main thread, then it could block the drawing ('freeze' the app) until the video is ready. 'Setting' the image will not display it immediately -- it just says "this view needs to draw, draw it on the next draw cycle" -- but a lot of work or IO on the main thread could block that view graph redraw execution because the thread is reading files, downloading videos, or a number of other things which prevent the main thread from moving forward.

Answer (score -1):

Image loading from NSData takes more time.
Instead you can simply use the following code:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileURL];
```

Try it.

Comment: are you serious, really? O.o

Answer (score -2):

So I tried the following:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL]];
    [self.imageView setImage:image];
    NSLog(@"imageView set");
});
```

And it is quite a bit faster. Not sure why though.

Comment: This should be worse as well as unstable since you are now doing UI updates on a background thread.

Comment: Have you tried using `dispatch_get_main_queue` instead? You say that it sometimes takes _minutes_ to load a local image, that's often an indication that you're accidentally on a background thread when using UIKit classes.

Comment: @omz thanks. I tried using dispatch_get_main_queue instead and it is actually even faster. So that seems to have solved it. When an IBAction triggers a function - is that being executed on the UI thread?

Comment: Normally yes, what do you get when you add log this in your action: `NSLog(@"%i", [NSThread isMainThread]);`?